# Minimum Android version for Monodroid applications?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm looking into using Monodroid for Android app development. I'd like to know what minimum version of Android is required for runnning Monodroid applications.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got an e-mail from Miguel de Icaza. He told me that the minimum Android version **for the preview version** is 2.1, but "he was told" (apparently by developers?) that it actually works with 1.6 and up.

Comment: Yes, Mono for Android supports API level 4 and up (Android 1.6 and later). We provide `Mono.Android.dll` for API levels 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, and 14; there'd be no point in providing an API level 4 `Mono.Android.dll` if we didn't support it. ;-) See also the TargetFrameworkVersion setting in the Project Properties panel.

Answer (score 3):

MonoDroid requires at least **Android 2.1** (SDK: API 7, revision 2)

Official source: http://monodroid.net/Installation

Comment: May I ask for a reference link? I couldn't find any info about this on their website.

Comment: +1 He is right, I've asked this on the monodroid IRC channel and got the same answer but with the extra information that they are planing to have 1.6 too.

Comment: Leyabaert: This does not seem to be true after all (see my reply)

Answer (score 0):

Minimum Android version that is supported in the latest release is 1.6. Reference:

http://monodroyd.wordpress.com/2011/12/17/where-is-androidmanifest-xml-in-mono-for-android/